# Centering Image and Text

Tags: html, css

I am creating a web page with 2 `<div>`s side by side. Each `<div>` will have 2 sections.
I want to center them (bring them to the middle of the `<div>`). I am trying to make this `<div>` responsive. In the website, 2 `<div>`s will be in one line, while in mobile one `<div>` will appear on one line and the other `<div>` will appear on a second line. I am trying to center the image and text of each section.

How can I accomplish that?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper div {
  min-height: 45px;
  padding: 1px;
}
#one {
  background-color: gray;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
#two {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 45px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #one {
    float: none;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: auto;
    border: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="one">
    <img src="http://livebodybuilding.com/images/fast-delivery.png" height="26" width="55" style="float:left; margin-top: 6px;" />
    <p style=" font-size:13px; color:#fff; line-height:1.5; font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;FREE DELIVERY         </strong>ORDERS OVER $100</p>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <img src="http://livebodybuilding.com/images/free-gift.png" height="26" width="31" style="float:left; margin-top: 6px;" />
    <p style="font-size:13px;  color:#fff; line-height:1.5; font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;FREE GIFT</strong> ORDERS OVER $100</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4okxw32v/

Comment: You can see 2 division there .. Each div was having img and text.. I need to bring them to center.. tried by using text-align, vertical-align ect. Text was coming to center but img was not coming to center...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all**, the use of floats in layout design is discouraged. It is generally not a good way of doing things, and usually if you're having a layout issue it comes down to a float problem. Instead you should use the `display: inline-block` setting. When using inline-block there are a couple of things to take into consideration.

1. Any white space between elements will be shown. To combat this you can set `font-size: 0` on the wrapper and then set `font-size: 1rem` on the children. This will set the font size in the content to the same size as that of the html selector.
2. You can prevent line-breaking if you set `white-space: nowrap` on the parent and then set `white-space: initial` on the children.

**Next** instead of adding an image and floating it inside the child you can use the css pseudo element ::before (or css2 :before) on the text container inside the element.

**Finally** to center the contents use `text-align: center` on the parent

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
  font-size: 0;
}
.wrapper div {
  font-size: 1rem;
  min-height: 45px;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
#one {
  background-color: gray;
}
#one p:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  background-image: url(http://livebodybuilding.com/images/fast-delivery.png);
  background-size: cover;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#two {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 45px;
}
#two p:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 2em;
  background-image: url(http://livebodybuilding.com/images/free-gift.png);
  background-size: cover;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  .wrapper div {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="one">
    <p><strong>FREE DELIVERY</strong> ORDERS OVER $100</p>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <p><strong>FREE GIFT</strong> ORDERS OVER $100</p>
  </div>
</div>
```